# Word for instance of faux pax redundancy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I subscribed to a word-of-the-day thing about 10 years ago. One of the words was a noun for the instance of describing something redundantly. Every now and then I hear someone do this and die not being able to remember the word for it. As luck would have it, I can't muster an example I feel very confident about but perhaps "it was too overdone" where "it was overdone" would suffice would suffice as an example...

- My ears will explode if I hear one more _____ out of this non-EL&U-subscribing scrub.

Comment: [There are innumerable questions like this all answering 'pleonasm' or 'tautology'.](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=Newest&q=pleonasm%20is%3aanswer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by the OP in [a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333134/word-for-instance-of-faux-pax-redundancy#comment760875_333134) (hat tip to [**@Silenus**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/129502/silenus)), the word being sought is **pleonasm**. From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleonasm):

> **pleonasm** ‎(*countable and uncountable, plural **pleonasms***)
>
> 1. (uncountable, rhetoric) Redundancy in wording.
> 2. (countable) A phrase involving pleonasm, that is, a phrase in which one or more words are redundant as their meaning is expressed elsewhere in the phrase.
>
>    *"The two of them are both the same" is a pleonasm (as the word "both" is redundant), as is "killed dead".*

Answer (score 1):

A Tautology

A tautology, or ‘tautology’, is using redundant words, or saying the same thing twice, or repeating the same idea in many words.

Tautological is a word you can use to describe phrases that are unnecessarily verbose in that way.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautological