# Term for describing what you like using particular adjectives

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, redundancy

Suppose someone makes statements like these:

> I like **tasty** food.
>
> I like **beautiful** pictures.
>
> I like **well-written** dramas / novels / articles / et cetera.
>
> I like **good** music.

As you see all those adjectives say something positive, yet entirely subjective, about the nouns the person likes. You might even say the adjectives are redundant, for example nobody likes food that's not tasty, but it depends on the person what type of food they'd call tasty.

Is there a term for this type of statement? An example sentence:

> These statements are ____, you should avoid them on your writing exams!

I found [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/212737/71848) where the adjectives describe a property that's already implied by the noun (a pleonasm). That's not the case here because you can say: *"that food is very tasty"*, which isn't a pleonasm, nor is it otherwise redundant.

Although when describing what you like by saying: *"I like tasty food"* it comes across as saying *"I like food that I find tasty"*, in which the *"that I find tasty"* part is already implied by the "I like" part.

After reading the Wikipedia page on pleonasms, I think my examples are pleonasms because the adjectives in bold are redundant *in the context of the sentence*. I am, however, looking for a more specific word (or subclass of pleonasms for that matter), it should at least imply that it's a pleonasm in the specific context (and not generally). A bonus would be if the term is specific to the verb adjective combination.

Comment: But people can and do like things they consider bad :P. See [So Bad It's Good](http://knowyourmeme.com/blog/white-papers/so-bad-it-s-good).

Comment: [Redundant, pleonasm, tautology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333134/word-for-instance-of-faux-pax-redundancy), and [redundant](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=redundant)

Comment: @Mari-LouA fixed it, seems the auto-correct on my phone wanted to ask its own question..

Comment: @Mitch yes _redundant_ and _pleonasm_ are both terms that fit my question (and the sentence), they are, however, not as specific as I'd like them to be. As I added in the last paragraph, the answer should at least encapsulate that the combination of words is only redundant in the context of the entire sentence. In my first example _tasty food_ in itself is not redundant, it becomes redundant because of the preceding _I like_, because if you like some food that means you find it tasty (but others may disagree).

Comment: You're saying that 'like' and 'good' are (arguably) logically redundant. "J'aime la bonne musique.", "Ich mag gute Musik.", "我喜欢好音乐。" Pretty universal. Nothing special about English. The English word to describe the situation is 'redundant'. If it is more than that, then you are asking for a philosophical explanation of exactly in what way it is redundant and there are lots of arguments for why or why not a particular nuance on pleonasm or redundancy would fit the situation you're describing. In the links I gave from ELU there's lots of commentary that would help you.

Comment: How would 'pragmatic redundancy' work for you? There's nothing in the denotations of the words and phrases that implies immediately a redundancy, but you're pointing out that it would be silly or perverse to like bad things (though of course some silly/perverse people _do_ like bad things).

Comment: @Mitch one might argue that if they like something you describe as 'bad', they (those who like it) would not. I am looking for a type of pleonasm as you find on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm#Types), but then suiting to these examples in the way described in the question. As you noted, there may very well be no such term, however, I'd be very interested to know it if there is one, hence my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I might call them "tautologies" or "truisms" or, to use an adjective, "self-evident".

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truism

Comment: The sole question was "Is there a term for this type of statement?" I gave a couple of replies that squarely answered that question. They *were* answers, complete answers, so I don't understand why you think it would be necessary to tack on a hundred extra words just so my answer looks long. I provided *two* citations of dictionary definitions backing up that these were correct answers and explaining why I had offered them, so I *really* don't know what you think was deficient about my response. It's almost as though you didn't read it.

Comment: I just realized that the comment I responded to isn't even signed--does that mean it was actually left by a bot, triggered only by the brevity of my response, and without any idea what I'd actually written? Would that be the reason why it seems to be someone off-point in the context of my answer?

Comment: I think it's because of the [question protection](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).